# How do I reverse a string of numbers in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, numbers, reverse, csv

I have a string which contains numerical values. I want to display the numerical values in reverse order.

An idea that doesn't work is to use the built-in reverse function:

```
my $j = "12,11,10,9";
my $k = reverse($j);
print $k;
```

But that code outputs:

```
9,01,11,21
```

When we want:

```
9,10,11,12
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Concise version:

```
my $j = "12,11,10,9";
print join ",", reverse split /,/, $j;
```

Parentheses version:

```
my $j = "12,11,10,9";
print(join(",", reverse(split(/,/, $j))));
```

If I decompose it a bit:

```
my $j = "12,11,10,9";
my @j = split /,/, $j;
print join ",", reverse @j;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
9,10,11,12
```

**NOTE**

- See `perldoc -f reverse`

Comment: It's a good idea to always write that `split /,/` as a reminder that it is a regular expression, not a fixed string.  Seen too many people try things like `split "|"` and not have any clue why it doesn't "work".

Comment: `reverse` doesn't expect a LIST exactly. It works on lists and scalars. `perl -le '$_ = reverse "IAHO"; print'`

Answer (score 3):

Put the string into an array and then reverse the array output.
You are simply reversing the complete string as it stands.

```
@j_array = split(/,/, $j);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not give any information on the origination of inputs, an alternative to the *common* `reverse()` answers is to issue a `sort`:

http://codepad.org/q3dIkzO4

```
my $j = "12,11,10,9";
my $k = join ',' , sort {$a <=> $b} split /,/ , $j;

print $j, "\n";
print $k;
```

---

The same thing broken down into more lines:

http://codepad.org/pwTvg1c1

```
my $j = "12,11,10,9";        # Original string
my @k = split ',', $j;       # Breaking the numbers into an array
@k = sort {$a <=> $b} @k;    # Applying a sort (could use "reverse()" in its place)
my $k = join ',' , @k;       # Combine the numbers with a comma

print $j,"\n";
print $k;
```

Comment: OP asked reverse order, his string is just an example, he never asked to sort it.

Comment: @sputnick: before I respond to that, what do you think reverse does?

Comment: Since you didn't respond, `reverse` is an address/byte-ordered sort.  The OP did not ask how the "reverse" was determined (programmatically or by the coder).  It could be a simple, short script for all you or I know and all the inputs could be in descending order.  Therefore, the above (an ascending sort), is the reverse order of the descending string he had given.

Comment: @vol7ron: Maybe so, but until you implement a comparator sorting in reverse address order, using `sort` is wrong.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus: how is it wrong?  The result is the same and you don't have any more information on what the inputs are - the OP didn't list them.  If all your inputs are in a CSV file of descending numbers, then an ascending sort is not wrong. --- ***Note:** I am using this as an additional answer, I also agree that `reverse` is the best choice* ---

Comment: Sorting a descending sequence reverses it, so it gives the right answer for this example.  For other examples, they differ, and the questioner has explicitly said they "want to display the numerical values in reverse order".

Comment: @CharlesStewart: still in full agreement - there aren't any other examples, which is the point I've continually made - if the OP was taking a CSV file filled with series of countdowns, then the above would suit the needs.  Part of the reason behind this *alternative* solution was to open the poster's eyes to see how one might `sort`.  If the OP did not know how to properly split/join a string, then he probably doesn't know how to sort, either.  I still stand behind the selected answer as the best answer and I'm still supporting my choice to provide this as an additional answer.